# Piping and colon commands in Vim

Tags: vim

I am a happy Emacs user. Anyway I find that there is a field where Vim can be better fitted to the job, this is inside the Linux terminal or Windows CLI, when you don’t want to open a separate window. There are some micro-Emacs distros for this lightweight tasks, but I still haven’t found a good one.

A typical Vim usage for me is as a more powerful alternative to `less`, e.g.:

```
 dir | vim -
```

Now I come to my problems/questions.

First, Vim starts from the top of the file. I’d like to position the cursor on the last screen line, but `dir | vim +L -` doesn’t work. I suppose because `L` is not an `ex` command. How can I overcome this?

When I finish browsing, and I want to quit I have to type: `:q!` five keys and with shifting (so two hands). Really a lot for a fast output check. Colon commands are very slow because  they need shifting. So I wonder if there is a way to replace the colon `:` with a function key, say F2, or the Tab key. Also I’d like to replace the `!` key with a non-shifted key, a single key like `` `-=[];'\,./ ``. Is this possible? What are the drawbacks of doing so?

### Edit

Note by colon replacement I mean replacing only the `:` symbol for every colon command, so I could type `<F2>q<CR>` for quit. For example in Emacs, you can assign the modifier key "Meta" (normally `Alt` key) to a non-standard key or remap all commands starting with the prefix `Ctrl-x` to a different key.

Comment: Not a direct answer, and I don't really understand what problem you're trying to solve but have you tried vifm? It's a great file manager that works in terminal/console environment.

Comment: @ErcanErden: I am trying to replace the colon with a single key character, e.g. F2. I mean replacing only the : symbol for every colon command, so I could type <F2>q<CR> for quit. `vifm` seems nice. Thanks I will try it. Anyway it has nothing to do with replacing the colon character.

Comment: GNU Emacs can happily work inside a terminal/console window too, with the `-nw` option.

Comment: that's good, but I have two problems. `dir |emacs -nw` gives the error `emacs: standard input is not a tty`; I am unable to select lines with CUA-mode using shift+arrow keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vim, `L` is used to place the cursor at the bottom of the window.

Use `$ command | vim - +8` to place the cursor on line 8.

Use `+$` to place the cursor on the last line.

You can place this line in `~/.vimrc` if you don't like `:q!`:

```
nnoremap <F2> :q!<CR>
```

Also, what do you dislike about `less`?

***edit***

```
$ command | vim - +'norm L'
```

puts the cursor on the last visible line.

You can use any key instead of `:` but Vim uses more or less the whole keyboard. You'll have to choose the replacement key wisely and use something like the following in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F2> :
```

Comment: `less` is very Vim like. After using it for about a couple of years, I thought I could step up to Vim. I don't need to go to the very last line of the command output, so `+$` doesn't solve it  (it is like not piping). Instead, I'd like to move the cursor to the last "visible line" (like with `L`) so that using the arrow again I can view the rest of the output. The problem with `+[num]` is that I do not know which is the last visible line number. My idea with the colon was more "outrageous". I'd like to replace only the `:` for every colon command, in order to write something like `<F2>q!<CR>`.

Comment: @antonio my vim starts much slower than less. maybe i have too many plugins. I don't know how is your vim.

Comment: +1 thanks. @Kent: mine too. Not a terrific delay, also because, when piping a command, I am starting a long read and Emacs, my natural spot, would be even slower. *May be the geeks here can give some tips about this*.

Answer (score 3):

In the installation of Vim73 on Ubuntu there is a script for running VIM more like "less". I'm using this in situations you describe.
The script is `less.sh` located at (replace with your installation path) `/usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.sh`

Here is the script in case you don't have it on your server:
script `/usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# Shell script to start Vim with less.vim.
# Read stdin if no arguments were given.

if test -t 1; then
 if test $# = 0; then
   vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' -
  else
   vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' "$@"
  fi
else
  # Output is not a terminal, cat arguments or stdin
  if test $# = 0; then
    cat
  else
    cat "$@"
  fi
fi
```

Notice that it's "turning off" all plugins.
If you want to do special things in your `.vimrc` when started this way you can start it using an alias with e.g.

```bsh
alias lessv='use_less=1 /usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.sh'
# use it:
lessv some_file
# and
dir | lessv   # no need for "-"
```

Then you can reference it as `$use_less` in `.vimrc`, and e.g. do `finish` before all of the usual mappings. There will be no errors if you start vim the "normal way" (you don't have to use tests like `exists("$use_less")`). And if there is no other good reason to use it, it's kind of fun having a variable named use_less.

There is some help with commands when opened with `less.sh`, just hit <kbd>h</kbd>
I also found it in vim help: [`:h less`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#less)
I tried to find the code for `less.vim` on Internet and use a link, but no luck. I think that the file is part of the installation though.

**Edit:**
**Windows:**
On windows in some installations there are also a `less.bat` to start vim more or less like less. I paste it in here if it's not part in the installation:
script `C:\Program\Vim\vim73\macros\less.bat`:

```bsh
@echo off
rem batch file to start Vim with less.vim.
rem Read stdin if no arguments were given.
rem Written by Ken Takata.

if "%1"=="" (
  vim --cmd "let no_plugin_maps = 1" -c "runtime! macros/less.vim" -
) else (
  vim --cmd "let no_plugin_maps = 1" -c "runtime! macros/less.vim" %*
)
```

**A final tip:**
<kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> are all mapped to scroll 1 line down (first placing cursor at bottom of window).
<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> are all mapped to **scroll** 1 line up (like less, first placing cursor at bottom of window).
To **move** up and down use `<Up>` and `<Down>`.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I need to study this script and possibly replicate it on M$ Windows. I suppose that `no_plugin_maps` can solve the slowness issue of `command |vim -` when compared to less.

Comment: In Windows my folder `c:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\macros\` has only a `less.sh` and a `less.vim` file. Strange no one spent some time to convert the `.sh` to a `.bat`.

Comment: @antonio: I added the `less.bat` script.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you could do:

```
ls | vim +$ +'map <F2> :' +'map <F3> !' -
```

Comment: I edited the my question clarifying my colon replacement idea.

Comment: @antonio: ok -- you can do whatever key mapping you want using the `map` command.